# Absolute path to a local file in the user computer

Tags: javascript, html, file-access

Is there local file manipulation that's been done with JavaScript that can actually get the absolute path to a file or folder when the user chooses with a directory or file picker?

Specifically, I'd like to read/show the ABSOLUTE PATH from a file and open the file if the user requests it. At this point I'm not worried about gaining permissions and am just assuming I already have full permissions to these files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not from the web browser, a website/app in a browser doesn't know much about the hosts it's hitting besides what the host/webserver tells it. You would have to build the path in the web server code and stick that into the site. If the files being served aren't somewhere under the web server root (like /var/www, or the project directory for something like a Python or Node server, etc.), it's considered unsafe to allow access to other paths, which is why paths absolute from the *web server root* are common, rather than absolute in terms of the host's storage.

Comment: Is there any alternative?

Comment: If the files you're making available for download are all in the same place, you could hardcode the path client-side. There's no dynamic way for the browser to figure out paths on a server host unless the webserver is making that information available, though.

Comment: What if the user wants to use the browser to open a local file on his computer?

Comment: In that case whatever's serving the web site would still need to be told about paths, unless you're using the `file://` protocol rather than serving the site, in which case the browser knows how to resolve relative paths to absolute paths. If your use case can allow for using the `file` protocol rather than http/https, my answer is incorrect.