# Store file location for repeated loading

Tags: flutter, file, dart, flutter-web

I am building a web-app using Flutter that needs to read in a local file supplied by the user. However, currently the file needs to be selected and manually added to the web-app each time the user logs in.

I don't believe it is currently possible to get the local directory path (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45296) for a file selected on Flutter Web.

Although I thought I'd ask anyway - would it be possible to automatically load the file when the web-app starts?

This would obviously only apply if the file is kept in the same on-device location.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most simple way is to use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences). The plugin supports all Flutter platforms.

```
await prefs.setString('path', path);
...
final String? path = prefs.getString('path');
```

Comment: I know that I can use shared preferences to store the path of the file, however, I am asking whether I can load a file from a path in Flutter Web without any user interaction (such as selecting the file from a file browser).

Comment: I've clarified the question.

Answer (score 0):

From my own continued research I have concluded that this is not currently possible for two reasons:

When a file is provided to a browser, the browser does not store the file's actual local path. This (I believe) is primary for security reasons. ([Absolute path to a local file in the user computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65622991/absolute-path-to-a-local-file-in-the-user-computer))

Secondly, I do not believe it would be possible for a web-app to automatically access a file in the user's local directory on startup. This is once again for security purposes - as such permissions could be abused for malicious purposes.

If anyone else has any input on this, it would improve my understanding and be very useful for future readers.